# Highlight certain rows in Listbox

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have a listbox I'm setting with a datasource of highscores

```
public class HighScore
{
    public string Username {get;set;}
    public int Score{get;set}
}

var IList<HighScore> HighScores = getAllTheScores();
MyListbox.ItemsSource = HighScores;
```

I want to change the background color of any rows which have a Username property equal to the currently logged in user (stored in AppSettings). I've seen Converters but this would need to somehow get hold of the currently logged in user which doesn't seem like something a converter should be responsible for getting.

I could also iterate the listbox items but from what I've seen that's not advised and I should be preferring binding to code behind drilling into controls.

Any suggestions as to how best achieve this much appreciated :)

Comment: In addition to @ShawnKendrot 's answer, you can use a DataTemplateSelector. Just another option! http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Implementing-Windows-Phone-7-DataTemplateSelector-and-CustomDataTemplateSelector

Comment: This was a nice solution and is what I've gone with for now. I think the other answer is perhaps the 'common' approach but this fit in easily with my current structure.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions. You already mentioned the first one, which is to use a ValueConverter. If value value is accessible from a viewmodel (recommended) than that is easy to pass along to the ValueConverter. If it is not stored in a view model then there are no worries with getting this from within the value converter provided it's named properly.

The second suggestion is to use a Behavior. The Behavior would be responsible for setting the background based on the user. I don't see much advantage here over a value converter except for the back that it's not a value converter. It would (almost) do the same thing. Overall I would recommend a value converter. Easy to implement, low code overhead and little xaml needed.